# Regex Python Grouping

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to produce the following "Query ID: XYZABC"

My code is as follows from a .txt file that has one instance of the following "Query= xyxysdfl;jas"

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

for line in open("/home/example.txt"):
    query_id = re.search(r"Query=(.*$)", line)
    if query_id != None:
        print("Query ID: " + query_id.group())
```

This produces the following:

Query ID: Query= xyslkjjdf

How can I eliminate the "Query="? I thought I was doing that by including the (.*$)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the first captured group:

```
query_id.group(1)
```

without any explicit group reference the 0-th group i.e. the whole match is produced.

---

**Notes:**

- `None` is a singleton in Python, so do the identity check by `is`:

  ```
  if query_id is not None:
  ```

  Or better as `None` is falsey, you can just do the truthy check:

  ```
  if query_id:
  ```
- It's not strictly needed, but for readability you should leave the end of line specifier, `$`,  out of the captured group:

  ```
  (.*)$
  ```

---

Taking the notes into account, the final form could be:

```
query_id = re.search(r"Query=(.*)$", line)
if query_id:
    print("Query ID: " + query_id.group(1))
```